# I can ping to any .dev in my Laravel Valet, but it always redirect me to Sites folder?

Tags: laravel, tld, laravel-valet

[I'm trying to access blog.dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dVcD.png)

I can ping anything blablabla.dev, but it always redirect me to Sites folder / localhost / 127.0.0.1. Just like picture above.

I tried

> localhost/blog/public/

or

> 127.0.0.1/blog/public/

it works. What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Here's what I did:

> 1. valet uninstall
> 2. sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl stop
> 3. composer global require laravel/valet
> 4. valet install
> 5. valet restart

Source: [laracast.com](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/valet-v112-update-just-keep-getting-the-it-works)

Answer (score 0):

Once Laravel Valet is installed, you need to tell it where to watch to serve your sites. For example, you could:

1. Open a terminal
2. Go to your project's directory
3. Run `valet link blog`
4. Open a browser and go to blog.dev

There is another way to serve your sites. Laravel Valet is very well documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet#serving-sites

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop your apache with `apachectl stop`
2. Restart your valet with `valet restart`
3. That's all